# how can I change value of array in a loop in mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I wrote a code in matlab as below:

```
T= ((1-(-1)) * rand([4,4],'double') + (-1) * ones(4,4));
for i=1:4
for j=1:i
T(j,i)=TT(i,j);
end
T(i,i)=0;
end
```

Now, I want to write this code in mathematica as below:

```
T = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4, 4}];
For[i = 1, i < 5, i++,
For[ j = 1, j < i, j++,
T[[j, i]] = T[[i, j]]]
T[[i, i]] = 0];
```

But it doesn't work!
Could you tell me about my mistakes?
Thank you.

Comment: Mandatory reading ... https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/why-should-i-avoid-the-for-loop-in-mathematica ... and if you continue your research over there you will learn why your attempt fails, and how to do what you want, both with and without `For`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SeedRandom[1234];
t = u = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {4, 4}];
t // MatrixForm
```

[image]

If must use `For`

```
For[i = 1, i < 5, i++,
  For[j = 1, j < i, j++, t[[j, i]] = t[[i, j]]]; t[[i, i]] = 0];
```

It mutates `t`

```
t // MatrixForm
```

[image]

One way to do this functionally

```
(l = LowerTriangularize[u, -1]) + Transpose[l]
```